# HTML: Should we use `type="text"` in HTML text-fields?

Tags: html, forms, input, attributes

I discovered that `<input>`s without the `type` attribute will use `type="text"` by default, as demonstrated by this code snippet:

```html
<!--Credit goes to http://www.asciitohex.com/ for generating HTML entities-->

<p>&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot;&gt;</p>
<p><input type="text"></p>

<p>&lt;input&gt;</p>
<p><input></p>
```

But as we all know, just because you don't have to include something doesn't mean it's a good idea to not. So, **should** `type="text"` **be included** regardless, **or should we simply omit it** to shave off a couple of bytes and work required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) states

> How an  works varies considerably depending on the value of its
>   type attribute, hence the different types are covered in their own
>   separate reference pages. If this attributes is not specified, the
>   default type adopted type is text.

And the official [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) for HTML4

> type=.... This attribute specifies the type of control to create. The default value for this attribute is "text".

And in [HTML5 the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute) specifies

> The missing value default is the Text state.

and  provides this example for how one might ask for the customer's name:

```
<form>
 <p><label>Customer name: <input></label></p>
</form>
```

Comment: so, required or not?

Comment: Clearly not required -- that is the meaning of "default is text" -- not to mention that the **HTML standard** provides an example that does not have a "type" specified.